# Recompose + TypeScript - type error on additional props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recompose

I am currently attempting to implement TypeScript on a project with Recompose to enhance the following component:

```
import { compose } from 'recompose';

// This is my Base Component that is reused throughout the App.
interface BaseOuterProps {
 value: any;
}

const StatelessBaseComponent = () => <div />;
const BaseComponent = compose<any, BaseOuterProps>(...)(StatelessBaseComponent);

// This is one of the higher components that needs to use the Base Component by enhancing it.

interface HigherInnerProps {
 value: any;
 something: any;
}

const HigherComponent = compose<HigherInnerProps, any>(...)(BaseComponent);
```

The problem I have is that when the HigherComponent type (HigherInnerProps) has more props than the BaseComponent type (BaseOuterProps), I receive the following error:

> Type 'ComponentClass< BaseOuterProps>' provides no match for the
>   signature '(props: HigherInnerProps & { children?: ReactNode; },
>   context?: any): ReactElement | null'

I have attempted to make the BaseOuterProps more flexible:

```
interface BaseOuterProps {
 value: any;
 [key: string]: any | void | null;
}
```

with no luck.

The types are provided by @types/react and @types/recompose.

Any ideas on how I could preserve the type linkage and satisfy the error requirements?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try

```
import { compose } from 'recompose';

// This is my Base Component that is reused throughout the App.
interface BaseOuterProps {
  value: any;
}

const StatelessBaseComponent = () => <div />;
const BaseComponent = compose<BaseOuterProps, any>(...) 
  (StatelessBaseComponent);

// This is one of the higher components that needs to use the Base Component by enhancing it.

interface HigherInnerProps {
  value: any;
  something: any;
}

const HigherComponent = compose<BaseOuterProps & HigherInnerProps, HigherInnerProps>(...)(BaseComponent);
```

Comment: thanks for the response and sorry for the delay. That would definitely work, however that means that the link between BaseComponent -> HigherComponent is not preserved.

I was hoping for it to also compare the exported BaseComponent type with the HigherComponent expected target type.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused what you mean by that?

Comment: Let's say that my BaseOuterProps is { value: string; } and my HigherInnerProps is { value: integer; }, I'd like some way for the type checker to tell me: "you're trying to plugin { value: string; } into { value: integer; }. This is wrong."

Answer (score 0):

1- create folder @types in root

2- create folder recompose and compose in it

```
├── src
├── @types
│   └── recompose
│       └── compose
│           └── index.d.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

3- add the following in tsconfig.json

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["./@types"],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

4- Add the following line in index.d.ts

```
declare module 'recompose/compose';
```